# A complete orthonormal system contained in a dense sub-space.

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let H be a separable complex Hilbert space. Let A be a dense sub-space of H. Is it possible to find a complete orthonormal system for H that is contained in A?

Comment: But, interestingly, this is not true for the nonseparable case.  A dense linear subspace need not contain a maximal orthonormal system.

Comment: @GEdgar: I was just thinking about this (as you can see from the ramblings in my answer).  Could you describe a counterexample?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

The proof is essentially the same as finding an orthonormal basis for $H$ itself.  As a subspace of a separable metric space, $A$ has a countable dense subset $\{x_n\}$.  Apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to $\{x_n\}$ to get an orthonormal set $\{e_n\}$.  By construction, the linear span of $\{e_n\}$ contains every $x_n$, so it is dense in $A$ and hence also in $H$, making $\{e_n\}$ a complete orthonormal system.

**Edit**: I'd be interested in seeing an answer which addresses the non-separable case.  I thought about using my argument with a transfinite induction, but it doesn't work.  Suppose we have an orthonormal subset of $A$, $\{e_i\}_{i < \alpha}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$.  Let $E_\alpha$ be the closed span of $\{e_i\}_{i <\alpha}$; if $E_\alpha \ne H$ then we can find some vector $x \in A \cap E_\alpha^c$.  The natural choice for the next basis vector $e_\alpha$ would be $e_\alpha = x - P_{E_\alpha} x$, as this will be orthogonal to all $\{e_i\}_{i < \alpha}$; but as $A$ is not closed, $E_\alpha$ need not be contained in $A$, so we could get $e_\alpha \notin A$ and this breaks down.

Of course the problem can happen only when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, so this seems to suggest that maybe there is something special about the separable case, and perhaps the statement is false in general.  But I couldn't think of a counterexample offhand.

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt algorithm I was taught only works on countable subsets where all the $x_n$ are linearly independent. But you can create such a linearly independent dense subset $\{y_n\}$ from $\{x_n\}$ by omitting all $x_n$ that are linearly dependent. The span of both subsets then remains the same.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat: Sure.  Or, if you apply Gram-Schmidt on a linearly dependent set, it spits out a bunch of zeros which you can just ignore.

Answer (score 24):

**nonseparable counterexample** (but the original question specifies "separable")

Pointed out to me in newsgroup [sci.math.research](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/00_incoming/innerprod) by Robert Israel in 2000.

See Dixmier, "Sur les bases orthonormales dans les espaces prehilbertiens",
*Acta Sci. Math. Szeged* 15 (1953) 29-30.

Let $H_1$ be an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space.  There is a 
linearly independent set $\{x_b: b \in B\}$ in $H_1$, indexed by a set $B$ of cardinality
$c$ (e.g. in $L^2([0,1])$ you could take $x_b$ for $0 < b < 1$ as the step function
$x_b(t) = 0$ for $t < b$, $1$ for $t \ge b$).  Let $H_2$ be the non-separable Hilbert
space with orthonormal basis $\{y_b: b \in B\}$ indexed by $B$.  Let $K$ be the linear
span of the vectors $\{x_b + y_b: b \in B\}$ in the direct sum $H_1  \oplus H_2$.
Then there is no orthonormal set in $K$ whose span is dense in $K$.
In fact:

1) Any orthonormal set in $K$ is countable.

Proof: Suppose $\{ z_a: a \in A \}$ is an orthonormal set in $K$.  We can write each
$z_a$ as a finite sum: $$z_a = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i (x_{b_i} + y_{b_i}),$$ where 
$\sum_i c_i x_{b_i} \ne 0$ since the $x_b$ are linearly independent.
Let $\{ w_j: j \in \mathbb N \}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H_1$.  For each $j$, we can
have $\langle w_j, z_a\rangle \ne 0$ for at most countably many $a$'s, so there are only
countably many $a$'s for which some $\langle w_j, z_a\rangle \ne  0$, and thus at most countably
many $a$'s for which any $\langle w, z_a\rangle \ne  0$ with $w \in H_1$.  But since 
$$\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_{b_i}, z_a\right\rangle = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_{b_i}\right\|^2 > 0,$$
this says that $A$ is at most countable.

2) The span of any countable orthonormal set is separable, and therefore
is not dense in $K$.

Comment: Nice answer. You should maybe clarify that $H_1$ is considered as the subspace $H_1 \oplus \{0\} \leq H_1 \oplus H_2$ in step 1). Also, you write "... there are **at** only countably many ...", i.e. the "at" should be removed.

Comment: Isn't that precisely the construction of a preHilbert space that admits **no** ONB?

Comment: May you explain more about given $B$ of cardinality $c$, how can we find a non-separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{y_b: b \in B\}$ indexed by $B$? Thanks!

Comment: Given a set $B$, the space $l^2(B)$ of all functions $x :  B \to \mathbb C$ such that $\sum_{b \in B} |x(b)|^2 < +\infty$ is your Hilbert space.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow the argument. Why $\overline{K}$ is not separable (since as you had shown, a separable space allows uncountably many linearly independent vectors)? In the last step, we know $\langle w, z_z\rangle\not=0$ for at most countably many $a$'s, but this is only true for a fixed $w$. But if we take $\sum c_i x_{b_i}$ as $w$, it's not fixed when $a$ varies?

Comment: @Justauser ... The distance between any two of the vectors $x_b+y_b$ is $\ge$ the distance between the two vectors $y_b$ which is $\sqrt{2}$. So the set $\{x_b+y_b : b \in B\}$ is not separable; $K$ is metrizable and has a subset which is not separable, so this tells us $K$ itself is not separable.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ a countable orthonormal basis for $H$. Since $A$ is dense in $H$, for each $n,k\geq 1$, let $a_{n,k}\in A$ such that $\lVert e_n-a_{n,k}\rVert\leq k^{—1}$. We apply Gram-Schmidt process to get an orthonormal family $\{b_{nk}\}\subset A$ (as $A$ is a subspace) which generates $\operatorname{Span}(a_{n,k},k,n\geq 1\}$. Then $\{b_{n,k}\}$ is an orthonormal basis.