# Orthonormal Sets in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let M be a dense linear subspace of H.
Can we find a complete orthonormal set $\{u_{\alpha}: \alpha \in A\}$ for H
in M?

I think the answer is negative in general, but I cannot find a counterexample.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: most probably we can... but I dont know if that works without choice axiom if $H$ is not separable.

Comment: Have you tried Gram-Schmidt in the separable case?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Max.

Comment: Obviously, if H is separable, the Gram-Schmidt procedure gives an affirmative answer.

Comment: This discussion came up in a previous question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201119/a-complete-orthonormal-system-contained-in-a-dense-sub-space . One of the contributors gave a counterexample for the non-separable case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to the following: does every pre-Hilbert space (= inner product space) $M$ admit an orthonormal basis?

It turns out that the answer is "no". A counter-example can be found in N. Bourbaki's *Topological Vector Spaces*, Exercise V.2.2.

I tried to solve the exercise, but I'm not quite sure that I understood it.

Let $H_1=\ell_2(\mathbb N)$, and $H_2=\ell_2(I)$, where $I$ is a set with cardinality $\mathfrak c$ (the continuum). Choose a linearly independent family $(x_i)_{i\in I}\subset H_1$ and an orthonormal basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ of $H_2$. Now let $H:=H_1\oplus H_2$ and $M:={\rm span}\,\{ x_i\oplus e_i;\; i\in I\}\subset H$. Let us try to show that $M$ admits no orthonormal basis.

First, note that, identifying $H_2$ with $\{ 0\} \oplus H_2\subset H$, we have $M\cap H_2=\{ 0\}$. This is rather easy to check using that fact that the $x_i$ are linearly independent.

Now, let us show that *any orthonormal family $\mathcal Z\subset M$ is countable*. To see this, choose an orthonormal basis $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $H_1=\ell_2(\mathbb N)\subset H$ and observe that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, we have $\langle f_n, z\rangle=0$ for all but countably many $z\in\mathcal Z$, because $\sum_{z\in\mathcal Z}\vert \langle f_n,z\rangle\vert^2<\infty$. Since by the previous remark, any $z\in\mathcal Z$ must satisfy $\langle f_n ,z\rangle\neq 0$ for at least one $n\in\mathbb N$ (otherwise we would have $z\in H_1^{\perp}=H_2$ and hence $z=0$), it follows that $\mathcal Z$ must be countable. Indeed, we have $\mathcal Z=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \mathcal Z_n$, where $\mathcal Z_n=\{ z;\; \langle f_n,z\rangle\neq 0\}$ is countable for each $n$.

It follows that if $M$ were to admit an orthonormal basis, then it would be separable. But this is not possible because 
$\pi_2(M)$ is dense in $H_2$ (since it contains all the vectors $e_i$) and $H_2$ is not separable.

Comment: This looks pretty good to me too, but then what do I know?  Anyway, +1!

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me too.  Nice example!

Comment: Thanks. One can find many nice things in Bourbaki's exercises...

Comment: Thanks, very very much for your fantastic example, Etienne. I checked it in all the details carefully, and it is perfectly correct! As I supposed, the answer was negative in general.

Comment: Yes, nonseparable spaces are sometimes strange objects... Glad that you found the answer useful!

Comment: I understand I can find a linearly independent family in $H_1$, indexed by $I$ with cardinality $\mathfrak c$. But may you explain more about how do we define $l^2(I)$, and why can we find an orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ of $H_2$ indexed by $I$?

Answer (score -1):

consider $X:=\left\{A\in\mathcal{P}\left(M\right): A \text{ is an ON-System }\right\}$ and $\subseteq$. Obviously each partially ordered chain $C$ has an upper bound in $X$: simply consider $\cup_{a\in C}a$.  By Zorn we get that there exists at least one maximal element of $X$. Take the maximal element, by definition it's an orthonormal Hilbert-basis.

> see comments. i will not delete this. (for documentation)

Comment: That looks right, +1!  Close to my thoughts on the matter, in any event;  that's probably why it looks right to me! ;-)  Will get back if I have any further ideas.

Comment: i had to edit, there is an important point missing.

Comment: OK, but I still think you're on the right track.  As of now, of course.  Keep me posted!

Comment: bad news... i'm sorry

Comment: How is $M$ a subspace?

Comment: what do you need that statement for? can you maybe drop orthogonality?

Comment: ah, *space* not set. sorry, my mistake. give me a moment :-)

Comment: @Max:  so *what is* the bad news, exactly?

Comment: @robert-lewis i edited. now i edit again and i think it's good news. please check it.

Comment: @Max:  I'll try and check it but I'm really busy right now so this may take awhile.  Best, RKL

Comment: What do you mean by ${ \cal P}(M)$?

Comment: the set of all subsets

Comment: That every maximal orthonormal subset of $M$ must be a Hilbert basis of $H$ is - if it is even true - nontrivial. How do you know its closed span is not a proper subspace whose orthogonal complement happens to have trivial intersection with $M$?

Comment: edited again, but this was my last edit. if there is another problem i will move the wrong/incomplete answer to the comments of the original question.

Comment: But the vector orthogonal to the ON system need not lie in $M$. You only know there is one in $H$.

Comment: How do you conclude that the maximal element is a basis for $H$?

Comment: if it wouldnt be a basis i could find a normed vector in it's orthogonal and add it to my maximal element

Comment: @Daniel: then it wouldnt be dense (if its not in the orthogonal but somewhere else project it to the orthogonal of the span of the vectors of the maximal elements. it' s in $M$ by definition)

Comment: I love playing around with Zorn :-) using it way to seldomly.

Comment: No. Consider $M\subset \ell^2$ the dense subspace of all sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms. Let $\xi = (\frac{1}{n+1})$, and $K = \langle\xi\rangle^\perp \cap M$. Take the system $(n+1)\cdot e_n-(n+2)\cdot e_{n+1}$ in $K$ and orthonormalise it. A maximal orthonormal subset of $M$ containing that system is contained in $\langle\xi\rangle^\perp$.

Comment: you didn't prove $M$ does not have any on-subsystem, you only proved that $\xi$ is not perpendicular to $span\left(2e_{1}-3e_{2},2e_{2}-4e_{3},...\right)$

Comment: bah, sorry. you proved that $K\perp \xi$. still i dont see why this should show that there is no complete on-subsequence of $M$. and btw: $K$ should be normalized. (so should $\xi$ and that's possible since $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ exists)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Nice counterexample.  It looks like the straightforward "take a maximal orthonormal subset" construction won't work.  max: It's a counterexample to your construction, though not to the original conjecture, which we still haven't solved.  $M$ definitely does have a complete orthonormal subset, since it contains the standard orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$.

Comment: the standard basis of $l^{2}$ would indeed be one example for a complete ons for $l^{2}$. when you state it's in $M$ that means............. ? ($M$ does have a complete ons for $l^{2}$)

Comment: please prove in detail why this should be a counterexample, i really don't see it. (and i think it isn't.)

Comment: have you read my comment "normalize $K$ and $\xi$"?

Comment: gentlemen behavour looks differently. you come here, claim something without proof and then you don't give a proper proof when asked for. i'll keep waiting though...

Comment: @Max If you want people to react to your messages, address them with an `@`, so they get notified and don't need to happen across the message by chance. $K$ is a subspace, what would normalising it mean? Normalising $\xi$ isn't necessary, since we're only interested in its orthogonal complement. The example shows that not every maximal orthonormal subset of $M$ needs to be a Hilbert basis of $H$. Note in fact that if you apply Gram-Schmidt to $(n+1)e_n - (n+2)e_{n+1}$, you obtain an orthonormal basis of $\langle\xi\rangle^\perp$, so that is already maximal (as an ON subset of $M$),

Comment: since $\xi \in H\setminus M$. I tentatively expect that a dense subspace of a Hilbert space contains a Hilbert basis, but proving that is not an easy application of Zorn's lemma.

Comment: $K$ is no subspace. $K$ is a subsystem. and it's neither orthogonal nor is it normal. just to give some examples: $\left<\left(n+1\right)e_{n}-\left(n+2\right)e_{n+1},\left(n+2\right)e_{n+1}-\left(n+3\right)e_{n+2}\right>=n^{2}+n$ and $\left<\left(n+1\right)e_{n}+\left(n+2\right)e{n+1},\left(n+1\right)e_{n}+\left(n+2\right)e{n+1}\right>=\left(n+1\right)^{2}+n^{2}$ so i ask you again: how is this a counter example? what exactly do you get by applying gram-schmidt?

Comment: i couldn't debug this comment, if i copy pasted it to the answer window everything looked fine in the preview.

Comment: Max: You claimed that the a maximal element is a basis for $H$, Daniel's example shows a maximal element of $M$ that is not a basis for $H$. You need to show why a maximal element constructed as above is a basis for $H$.

Comment: no he didnt since he didnt take any on system

Comment: Regardless, you need to show why a maximal element constructed as above is a basis for $H$.

Comment: if the maximal element (let's call it $m$) wouldn't be a basis there would be an element $e$ in it's complement and so would $f:=pr_{m^{\perp}}\left(e\right)$ (w.l.o.g. normed) because $M$ is a sub*space* thus $\left\{f\right\}\cup m$ would be a ons in $X$ and biger than $m$ which is not possible. ($pr_{m^{\perp}}$ is the projection on the orthogonal of the span of $m$)

Comment: anyway i'm done with this discussion, unless i see a rigurous counter example (remember: we need a maximal orthonormal set in $M$ which does have an orthogonal complement in $H$. is it possible that you still dont see your problem? hint: $M$ is dense in $H$)

Comment: I'm still not seeing it. How do you know the element in the complement is in (or has a representative in) $M$? $M$ is not closed.

Comment: @Max $K$ is the intersection of the orthogonal complement of the span of $\xi$ - a subspace - with $M$ (also a subspace). Thus it is a subspace. "what exactly do you get by applying gram-schmidt?" By applying the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to $\{ (n+1)e_n - (n+2)e_{n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ we get an orthonormal system in $M$. In fact, an orthonormal basis of $\langle\xi\rangle^\perp$, and therefore a maximal orthonormal system in $M$.

Comment: ye, the closedness it is, thanks! daniel: on the first glance i didn't see that $\left(1,0,...\right)$ is not in the span of $K$.