# Dense Subspace: ONB

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

*This might be a duplicate. If so, then please let me know. Thanks!*

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a dense subspace $\overline{Z}=\mathcal{H}$.

Then it provides an ONB: $\mathcal{S}\subseteq Z$

*(I guess it can be shown by slightly adjusting the usual proof via Zorn's lemma...)*

Comment: This is **not** true if $\mathcal{H}$ is **not** assumed to be separable. See here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/201149/151552.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Oh pretty bad; then does it still hold that $x\in\mathcal{H}_{ac}\iff\nu_x\ll\lambda$?

Comment: I am sorry, but: What is $\mathcal{H}_{ac}$? What are $\nu_x$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: @PhoemueX: No problem, it wasn't clear from the context anyway. Actually I meant $\mathcal{H}_{pp}:=\overline{\mathrm{span}\{\phi\in\mathcal{H}:\exists\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:T\phi=\lambda\phi\}}$ for a normal operator $T:\mathcal{D}(T)\to\mathcal{H}$ and $\nu_x(A):=\|E(A)\phi\|^2$ for its associated spectral measure $E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$

Comment: @PhoemueX: Ah and $\lambda$ was meant to be the Lebesgue measure but not needed here as now it is $\nu_\phi$ discrete iff $\phi\in\mathcal{H}_{pp}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I just realized that this cannot be true for the following reason:*

Assume every dense subspace would provide an ONB for the Hilbert space:
$$\overline{\mathcal{S}}=\mathcal{H}\quad(\mathcal{S}\subseteq Z)$$
Then, it would serve as well as an ONB for the subspace:
$$\overline{\mathcal{S}}\supseteq Z$$
But there are preHilbert spaces which do not admit any ONB (see Bourbaki or [Robert Isreal](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/00_incoming/innerprod)).