# The existence of orthonormal basis in the dense subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $V$ is a dense linear subspace of $H$. Can we find an orthonormal basis of $H$ such that all elements are in $V$?

Comment: Can we always carry on Gram-Schmidt on a given basis?

Comment: If $H$ is separable, you simply have to apply Gram-Schimdt orthonormalization in a dense countable set contained in $V$. I would guess this is not true in general, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201119/a-complete-orthonormal-system-contained-in-a-dense-sub-space answers the separable case and provides a counterexample for the non-separable case.