# Subsec. 4.1-8 in Kreyszig's functional analysis book: Does every inner product have a total orthonormal set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

> In every Hilbert space $H \neq \{0 \}$, there exists a total orthonormal set.

I think I've understood the proof given by Erwin Kreyszig in *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications*.

The following questions arise in my mind:

Is there a total orthonormal set in \emph{every} inner product space?

Is there a total proper subset in every normed (or Banach) space?

A subset $M$ of a normed space $X$ is said to be total in $X$ if span of $M$ is dense in $X$.

If $X$ is an inner product space and if $M (\neq \emptyset) \subset X$ is total in $X$, then 
$$M^\perp \colon= \{ \ x \in X \ \colon  \ \langle x, v \rangle = 0 \ \mbox{ for all } \ v \in M \ \} =  \{0 \}.$$

If $X$ is a Hilbert space and if $M^\perp = \{0 \}$, then $M$ is total in $X$.

Comment: In the Hilbert space $\{0\}$, $\varnothing$ is a total orthonormal subset.

Answer (score 0):

In his answer to this question ([A complete orthonormal system contained in a dense sub-space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201119/a-complete-orthonormal-system-contained-in-a-dense-sub-space)), GEdgar constructs a (non-separable) Hilbert space $H$ and a dense subspace $V\leq H$, such that $V$ contains no orthonormal basis for $H$.

Thus, $V$ contains no total orthonormal family for $V$, since otherwise the span of this family would be dense in $V$ and thus in $H$, so that the total orthonormal set would be an orthonormal basis for $H$.

For the more general question (total proper subset), simply take $M=X\setminus \{0\}$.