# Orthonormal Bases in a Hilbert Space and Vector Subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $S$ a vector subspace of $H$ which is dense in H. Does there exist an orthonormal basis $(u_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ of $H$ such that $\{ u_{\alpha} :    \alpha \in A \} \subseteq S$?

I think the answer is generally negative, but I can't find a counterexample. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201119/a-complete-orthonormal-system-contained-in-a-dense-sub-space) that can be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marko, for having drawn my attention to this post, which contains the answer to my question. As I suspected, the answer is generally negative.

Comment: No problem Maury. It is an intersting question. At first I thought the answer is true but the true beauty of mathematics is that there are some answers that are not obvious or even intuitive.