# Existence of orthonormal basis for $L^2(G)$ in $C_c(G)$.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis, orthonormal, locally-compact-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a locally compact (Hausdorff) group endowed with the Haar measure. It is well-known that the compactly supported functions $C_c(G)$ are dense in $L^2(G)$. In the book

> "*Operator algebras, theory of $C^{*}$-algebras and von Neumann algebras*"

written by Bruce Blackadar it is claimed (without proof) that $L^2(G)$ admits an orthonormal basis contained in $C_c(G)$.

I didn't immediately see why this is true. So I started to look for an argument and encountered an [MSE-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201119/a-complete-orthonormal-system-contained-in-a-dense-sub-space), which shows that it is not always possible to find an orthonormal basis for a non-separable Hilbert space in a given dense subspace.

I know that Blackadar's claim is true in the following cases:

- If $G$ is second countable, then $L^{2}(G)$ is separable. So one can use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to find an orthonormal basis in $C_{c}(G)$.
- If $G$ is compact and abelian, then $\widehat{G}$ (= Pontryagin dual) is an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(G)$. Note that $\widehat{G}$ can be viewed as a subset of $C_{c}(G)$ in this case.

But does anyone know why Blackadar's claim is true (or false) for general $G$? Or does anyone know a reference for this?

Comment: Do you know the answer for non-separable, non-abelian compact groups (I don't)?

Comment: @Plop No, unfortunately not. Everything I know is mentioned in the post.

Comment: And is there a chance that you missed a line saying "from now on, we assume $G$ to be second countable" somewhere in the book :)? (even though your question is legitimate)

Comment: @Plop I checked again, just to be sure, but no. Moreover, he mentions the existence of this ONB to sketch a proof for a result which is known to be true for general locally compact groups.

Comment: Hmmm, is it in the proof of Theorem II.10.4.3. on the author's website? Well, if I had read the book, my first reaction would probably have been: "if such a claim is made without further explanation in the non-separable case, it's probably because the author has forgotten to explicitly add a separability hypothesis".

Comment: Oh, I will take a look at $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. EDIT: Hahaha, ok, the claim is obvious for discrete groups...

Comment: @Plop It is indeed Theorem II.10.4.3. But it is known that this theorem is also known for non-second-countable groups. So I don't think he forgot to add further hypotheses.