# Example of an inner product space with no orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space with an inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$. A system of non-zero vectors $B = \{ x_\alpha \}$ from $X$ is called *orthonormal* if
$$
(x_\alpha, x_\beta) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \alpha \neq \beta,\\
1, & \alpha = \beta.
\end{cases}
$$
The orthonormal system $B = \{ x_\alpha \}$ is called an *orthonormal basis* for $X$ if the subspace of $X$ generated by finite linear combinations of elements of $B$ is dense in $X$.

It is well-known that every separable inner product space has an orthonormal basis. What is some good example of non-separable inner product space with no orthonormal basis? I am interested in any concrete example.

P.S.: The definition of orthogonal basis given includes uncountable cases as well.

Comment: A previous answer of mine.  $K$ is an incomplete non-separable  inner product space with no complete orthonormal system...  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/201149/442   (Dixmier, 1953)

Comment: Thank you! Apparently, this construction is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 8):

Every Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$  has  a maximal orthonormal system $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}.$ We restrict to the case of infinite dimensional space $\mathcal{H}.$ Consider an arbitrary element $x\in \mathcal{H},$ which does not belong to the linear span of $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}.$ Due to the Bessel inequality for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ the   set
$$\{\alpha\in A\,:\,|\langle x,e_\alpha\rangle| \ge 2^{-k} \}$$ is finite, therefore the set
$$\{\alpha\in A\,:\,\langle x,e_\alpha\rangle \neq 0\}$$ is countable. Let
$$\{\alpha\in A\,:\,\langle x,e_\alpha\rangle \neq 0\}=\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$$ By the  Parseval identity we get
$$\|x\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_{\alpha_n}\rangle |^2$$ hence
$$\lim_N \sum_{n=1}^N \langle x,e_{\alpha_n}\rangle e_{\alpha_n}\underset{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}x$$
Summarizing finite linear combination of the elements of $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ are dense in $\mathcal{H}.$

**Remarks**

1. Let $V$ be an incomplete inner product space and $\mathcal{H}$ denote its completion. Assume $V$ contains an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}.$ Then the reasoning above shows that the linear span of the elements of the basis is dense in $V.$
2. Let $V$ be a separable inner product space and $S$ a countable dense subsets of $V.$ Let $S_0$ be a maximal linearly independent subset of $S.$ By the Gram-Schmidt procedure applied to $S_0$ we obtain a countable maximal orthonormal set $B$ in $V.$ Then $B$ is an orthonormal basis in $\mathcal{H}.$ Moreover $B$ is linearly dense in $V.$ Hence we can apply the first remark.
3. An inner product space should be incomplete and not separable in order to satisfy the requirement of OP.

Answer (score 7):

**SUMMARY**. This is not a strict answer to the question. Here, I show a concrete example of a Hilbert space (that is a complete inner product space) that does not admit *countable* orthonormal bases.

---

**ANSWER**. If an inner product space $X$ has a countable orthonormal basis, it must be separable. Indeed, letting $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ denote such basis, the set
$$
\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^N \lambda_j e_j\ :\ \Re \lambda_j\in\mathbb Q,\ \Im\lambda_j\in\mathbb Q,\ N\in\mathbb N\right\}$$
is dense and countable.

So to answer your question it suffices to exhibit an example of a non-separable inner product space. The standard one that I know of is the following:
$$
X:=\left\{f\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb C\text{ measurable }\ :\ \lVert f\rVert:=\sqrt{\lim_{T\to \infty}\frac2T\int_{-T}^T \lvert f(t)\rvert^2\, dt}<\infty\right\}.$$
(This is superficially similar to the usual space $L^2(\mathbb R)$, but it is actually rather different). The set
$$
\mathcal X:=\left\{\chi_\xi(x):=\exp(i\xi x)\ :\ \xi\in\mathbb R\right\}$$
is uncountable and orthonormal in $X$. Therefore, $X$ is not separable.

*Remark*. Actually, $\mathcal X$ is also complete, hence a basis. Proof: let $f\in X$ satisfy $\langle f, \chi_\xi\rangle=0$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb R$, we claim that $f=0$. Note indeed that
$$
\langle f, \chi_\xi\rangle=\lim_{T\to \infty}  \mathcal F\left(f\frac{\mathbf 1_{[-1, 1]}(\frac{\cdot}{T})}{2T}\right)(\xi),$$
where $\mathcal F(u)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x)e^{-ix\xi}\, dx=\widehat{u}$ denotes the Fourier transform. By the convolution theorem,
$$
0=\langle f, \chi_\xi\rangle = \lim_{T\to \infty} \left(\widehat{f}\ast\frac{\sin(T\cdot)}{T\cdot}\right)(\xi)=(\widehat{f}\ast \delta)(\xi)=\widehat{f}(\xi), $$
so we conclude that the (tempered distributional) Fourier transform of $f$ vanishes, so $f$ vanishes as well, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: Probably by "orthonormal basis" you mean _countable_ orthonormal basis... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: of course! :-) I checked on Rudin's R&CA and indeed he writes of general orthonormal bases, which then in practice are always countable. I wouldn't know how useful a non-countable basis could be, since even summing on an uncountable set is tricky. But in principle one can perfectly well define bases of any cardinality, as you rightfully remark.

Comment: Indeed, I mostly ignore Hilbert spaces with uncountable bases, except to make the point that it's possible. :) And, to bring up the fun point that a finite-valued infinite sum of positive real numbers can be at most countable. So, even in an uncountably-orthonormal-based Hilbert space, any given vector is just a countably-infinite sum of those basis vectors. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But in fact, I also meant uncountable orthogonal bases. In Kolmogorov&Fomin's book, I faced with the problem: Find an example of non-separable inner product space without any orthogonal basis. In the same book, the definition of an orthogonal basis is given without mentioning countability. I understand that such spaces are rather exotic, but these exist, right? :)

Comment: @AlexeyMagazev: I updated the answer, now it contains counterexamples to both the countable and uncountable basis cases.

Comment: I don't understand your part 2. Certainly not every inner product space with an ONB in the sense of this question is complete. For example, if $(e_\alpha)$ is an ONB of a Hilbert space, then the linear span of $(e_\alpha)$ has an ONB (namely $(e_\alpha)$), but it is only complete if $(e_\alpha)$ is finite.

Comment: Btw, I would say the *standard* example of a non-separable Hilbert space is $\ell^2(I)$ for $I$ uncountable. ;)

Comment: A little question about Part 2: Why does having an orthonormal basis imply completeness? I know that completeness implies the existence of an orthonormal basis, but not vice versa ...

Comment: @MaoWao Do I understand correctly that $\ell^2(I)$ is the space of square-summable functions $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ with countable supports?

Comment: @AlexeyMagazev Yes, that's right (or functions with values in $\mathbb C$ if you want a complex Hilbert space).

Comment: @MaoWao: You are absolutely right; actually, even the Hilbert space in this answer is isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$ via $\chi_\xi\mapsto \delta_\xi$, where $\delta_\xi(x)=1$ if $x=\xi$ and $0$ otherwise. The latter is an element of $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$. However, I wanted to try and give a more "concrete" example.

Comment: Sure. But my comment on part 2 still stands. In fact, the set $\mathcal X$ from your answer is an ONB of $Y$ in the sense of this question.

Comment: @MaoWao: it seems that there is a problem with definitions. To me, ONB = "complete orthonormal system". Which by the way is also in the question. The point of my answer is: $\mathcal X$ is orthonormal both in $X$ and in $Y$, however it is only complete in $X$, hence ONB only in $X$.

Comment: The question states that an ONB is an orthonormal system whose linear span is dense. This is clearly the case for $\mathcal X$ in $Y$.

Comment: @MaoWao: Fair enough. With this definition of "orthonormal basis" there is no point in considering incomplete spaces, so I removed that PART 2. I was actually not reading the question carefully. Thanks!

Comment: I would say that incomplete spaces is where it gets really interesting. For complete spaces, the existence of an ONB is well-known. For incomplete spaces things get tricky. An ONB always exists for separable spaces, but may fail to exist in non-separable spaces. Check out the answer linked to in GEdgar's comment to the question.